# what happens if a python program contains an error, will it generate a .pyc file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read that python generates a .pyc file when we execute a python script for the first time and stores it in a _pycache directory but what will happen if python script has an error at some line. will it generate bytecode?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the error. If the file contains syntax errors and *cannot be parsed*, then no bytecode can be created. If it contains *runtime errors*, that follows the creation of bytecode and won't influence it. I don't know if there are specific exceptions to that rule, but it would make sense.

Comment: ok, I understood the concept. Thanks for your answer @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python never deletes a cache (bytecode) file, so if it gets written it stays.  It gets written after compilation (if there are no `SyntaxError`s) and before execution—even before finding out that, say, an `import foo` on the first line refers to a nonexistent module.

So you can almost say that the file is written unless a `SyntaxError` is raised, except that other things can raise that: an `import` inside the first module, an `exec`/`eval`/`compile`, or an explicit `raise`.  It *is* possible to distinguish these programmatically if needed by counting traceback frames to see if the (first) module ever began execution.